# dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv when using javac to compile on MacOS

Tags: java, macos, compiler-errors, dyld

I have just started using Java on my MacOS, and I got the following error when compiling my first .java file using javac.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: _iconv
  Referenced from: /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
  Expected in: /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
 in /usr/lib/libcups.2.dylib
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Could anyone solve the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you have `DYLD_SEARCH_PATH` set to something including `/opt/local/lib` which contains a copy of `libiconv.2.dylib` which is interfering with the system copy of the same library. I'm guessing you installed macports? If you unset the variable then you should be able to compile the java program.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have set an DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH as /opt/local/lib and macports. I reset this DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH to empty and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

This is a regular issue when using macports and you set the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable to have `/opt/local/lib`. There are some libraries in macports which can interfere with system libraries and when you're at the command line will cause programs to fail to start up in that case.

Workarounds are unsetting the variable for the shell, but this can cause issues running other macports applications. If you're just running from the command line, you can create functions in your `.bashrc` that run the commands without the variable e.g.

```
java() 
{ 
    env DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH= java "$@"
}
```

and similar for javac, etc. This will allow you to leave the variable defined, but prevent the interference when invoking these specific command-line tools.

I've moved from [macports](https://www.macports.org) to [homebrew](http://brew.sh) which is a little better behaved in this regard - it generally refuses to put things in the path which interfere with the system libraries without forcing the issue - this is a personal choice thing, though, and is not advising you to switch.